# ASCII code in binary code Es in C here under is my code but it's not working...in output i need like [C 067: 01000011]

Tags: c, binary, ascii, codeblocks

I Have a ex for my school work and i have tried in another ways it seems to not work
Input string= "every sentence"
in output i need to codify that string from ascii to binary code for example if i put C from input it has too bee ASCII 067 and Binary 01000011.
My code is:

```
void main()
{ 
    char string[20];
    int n, count = 0; 

    printf("Enter the no of characters present in an array \n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf(" Enter the string of %d characters \n" , n);
    scanf("%s", string);

    while (count < n)
    {
        printf(" %c = %d\n", string[count], string[count] );
        ++ count ; 
    }

    printf("trasformo in bit:");
    int i;
    int j;
for(i=0;i<n/10;i++)
{
    if(i<10)
    {
        printf("SO%d " , i);
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            while(string[i*10+j]!=0)
            {
                if(string[i*10+j]%2==1)
                {
                    printf("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("0");
                }
                string[i*10+j]/=2;
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("T");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("S%d " , i);
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            while(string[i*10+j]!=0)
            {
                if(string[i*10+j]%2==1)
                {
                    printf("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("0");
                }
                string[i*10+j]/=2;
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("T");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't went through your code (too complicated) but the first thing that meets the eye is this statement

```
for(i=0;i<n/10;i++)
```

For every value of n < 10, the code won't be executed, i do not think that this is what you want.

A simple(r) solution could be:

```
char *str = "every sentence";
int n = strlen(str);

char bin[9];
bin[8] = '\0'; //make null-terminated string

int c;

// for each character of the input string
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    
    // character at pos i
    c = str[i];

    // ascii2bin
    // before we print the binary string we would normally have to revert it
    // first, but we simply fill the buffer from back to front.
    // we intentionally do 8 steps to fill the gap with zeroes, so we
    // always have 8 digits
    for (int j=7; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (c > 0) {
            bin[j] = (c % 2) + '0';
            c /= 2;
        } else {
            bin[j] = '0';
        }
    }

    // print the character in binary format
    printf("%s ", bin);

}
```

You say, that the output has to be in the form

```
S0= c binary code S1= i binary S2= a binary S3= o binary
```

then replace the

```
printf("%s ", bin);
```

with

```
printf("S%i= %c %s ", i, str[i], bin);
```

And i highly recommend, that you read the documentation to **printf**.

Comment: i need ascii value too in output

Comment: Then add it to the output. %d for the ascii value. str[i] is untouched.

Comment: have u got any social so i can contact u better cause i need help asap

Comment: I don't like to share, put it in you question, i will answer it. I could open a chat, are you able to join?

Comment: Sorry, i've read in the faq, that you need 20+ reps to join. Besides it would be a public room, i think that would be overdozed. Best use your question section.

Comment: where i have to put that printf for ascii value output

Comment: Show me how you want the output to be. Lets say the input would be "abc", what do you expect as output? Don't mind the right decimal or binary for now.

Comment: i've finished the ascii output and know i have to put terminator character to finish it, my excercize was "fragmentation exercise of a string into packets: generate a check character with even parity to be appended to the characters of the packet followed by the character E." how can i continue?

Comment: Could we see your end result? Right now, I am not sure if i gave you a right answer.

Comment: I see that you separated the decimal from the binary output. I didn't know the requirements. But since you managed it, congratulations.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1KCBqvP (this is output)     it has to be like S0= c binary code S1= i binary S2= a binary S3= o binary ...i didn't know how to do that

Comment: I've added some code to my answer, have a look.

Comment: it has to be 10 packets of S0..like s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10 and after that i will put a terminal letter E to conclude the code